# How do I get the value of the item selected in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-intent, selecteditem

I thought I could use the `position` `int`, but when I click on the item in the list view, nothing happens. Please help!

```
ListView d = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.apo); 
ArrayAdapter adapt = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
  R.array.algebra, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); 
d.setAdapter(adapt); 
d.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
        if (position == '0') {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, Alqv.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (position == '2') {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Algebra.this, qfs.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position here is an integer, so instead of comparing with chars ('0', '1'...), it should be compared with integers.

```
 if (position == 0) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Algebra.this, Alqv.class);
        startActivity(intent);
 }
 if (position == 2) {
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(Algebra.this, qfs.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The position here is an integer. Can't compare with chars('0','0').